# Extract data between two time range in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I need to extract data between two time range, basically I want to extract whole data which have been transacted in morning.

```
Column_A
2017-06-01 12:23:19
```

Data Type - String

I tried below query, but it didn't work.

```
use retail_apac;

select * 
from bills
where concat(hour(Column_A),':',minute(Column_A),':',second(Column_A)) between '05:00:00' and '12:00:00';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    select * 
    from bills
    where substr(Column_A , 12) between '05:00:00' and '12:00:00';
```

or

```
    select * 
    from bills
    where (hour(Column_A) between 5 and 11) OR (HOUR(Column_A)=12 and MIN(Column_A)=0 AND second(Column_A) = 0) ;
```

or (more relaxed)

```
    select * 
    from bills
    where hour(Column_A) between 5 and 11;
```